# Find index of object in a state array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm managing a cart array composed by a state:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([{
key: 1
name: 'Product Name'
value: 399
productID: 1456
```

I'm adding items to it through a function, and sorting by Keys:

```
  function addToFav() {
    setFavs((arr) => {
      const newFavs = [...arr];
      const existingItem = newFavs.find((i) => i.id === infos[id-2].id);
      if (existingItem) {
        console.log('Este item já está nos favoritos');
      } else {
        newFavs.push({
          nome: infos[id-2].nomeCompleto,
          value: infos[id-2].valor,
          id: infos[id-2].id,
          quantity: 1,
          key: infos[id-2].key
        }).sort((a, b) => {
          return a.key - b.key
        });
      }
      return newFavs;
    });
  }
```

My add and subtract functions are working fine. But I need a function to remove the object from array. As it is now, i'm using :

```
export const CartElement = (props) => {
 ...
 const cartRemove = (index) => {
    setCart([
        ...cart.splice(index, 1)
    ])
  }
...
<... onClick={() => { cartRemove(props.key - 1)}}>
```

The problem is: I can't find the object index with a function in the array. The key doesn't work since I don't always have all keys on the array. How can I find the index of the 'props' object on the state array? Or is there any other way I could slice specific array from the cart basket, like Array.filter or something

Answer (score 0):

How do you display items? If you use the `map` method, its callback can receive an index param. You should pass it to your functions `addToFav` or `cartRemove`.

Checkout [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)